# CSV error on phone number

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

On my website I generate a CSV file from a database of users. 
When I view the CSV file in my browser all the information comes up as it was submitted by the users, but when I download the CSV file and open it in Excel, the phone number column seems to corrupt somehow. For example, below is the csv data for a single user, as viewed in my browser:

"11","Daniel","Nuttall","xx Alder Street","","HUDDERSFIELD","West Yorkshire","HD1 6xx","xxx@xxxxxxx.co.uk","447769697410","item 2","50","on","on"

But when I open this in Excel, the phone number changes to: 4.4777E+11

All the other info stays the same, its just the phone number that changes. 
Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel chooses a wrong format for the cell. Rightclick the cell and choose "Format Cells...". Choose "Text" to get plain text. You might want to do this first for the whole table.

[image: Format Cells]

Comment: Thanks for the response. This hasn't changed the value in the spreadsheet. However, I have noticed that the correct value shows up in the 'fx' bar when you select the cell. So why does it still show up as 4.4777E+11 in the spreadsheet?

Comment: I resolved it by changing the format to 'number' and removing the decimal places so all is good now, but I'd still like to know what causes it to change to a somewhat random value of 4.4777E+11

Comment: @nutman - It's not a "somewhat random number". 447769697410 is 447,769,697,410 with the thousands separator so you can see it's 4.47769697410 * 10E+11 which gets truncated to what you see

Comment: If you don't format a field with a large number, Excel will assume scientific notation (i.e. 4.4777E+11) for any large numbers.  Another solution would be to output the phone numbers with some sort of formatting already added so that Excel sees it as a text field rather than a number field by default.

Comment: oh god yeh i didn't even realise it was a ten to the power x number lol. Was just viewing it in my mind as a phone number. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Another solution is to import the CSV file into a new workbook.  In the Import Text Wizard, you can then select the format you want for the colomns and see what Excel has guessed for the columns.